# C# Using NAudio Library parse CC enum

Tags: c#, midi, naudio

Just having trouble to realize something here. I receive a MidiInMessageEventArgs from my midi controller(samson conspiracy)

I Reading Control changes so I create de proper class

```
ControlChangeEvent cce = e.MidiEvent as ControlChangeEvent;
```

I can read the CC using

```
cce.Controller.ToString()
```

But what is driving me nuts is when I use CC1 it returns me the text(Modulation) and not just the number 1.

I understand this CC is widely used for modulation but I need to get the number. Does someone know how to get that? or even a way to parse it using the MidiController Enum?

Thx